# Как разместить изображение также, как на примере?

Tags: html, css

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
</body>
<div style="position:relative; top:1475px;">
  <div style="background-image:url(img6.jpg); overflow:hidden; position:relative; max-height:1000px; max-width:50%; background-size: cover;opacity:1; top:; font-family:arial">
     <div style="position:relative; top:150px;">
       <div style="text-align:center; font-family:arial; font-weight:700; font-size:40px;"><strong>БОКС</strong></div>
       <div style="line-height: 1.5; font-family:arial; font-weight:700; font-size:20px;">
       &nbsp;Занятия боксом помогут быстро привести себя в<br>форму.
       Справиться со стрессами и выплеснуть всю<br>накопившуюся негативную энергию.
       Это гарантирует<br>спокойствие.
       Занятия боксом научат: управлять силой<br>и мощностью своих рук.
        Грамотно уходить от ударов,<br>обретать лидерство даже всамых сложных ситуациях.
      </div>
     </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Необходимо разместить изображение в блок, в полном размере. С какими тегами не игрался, не получается никак. Вот как должно быть https://poedinokclub.ru/
[[image: Слева, мои мучения, но надо из мучений, превратить это в блок, как здесь.]

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: предоставьте свой код пожалуйста

Comment: Залейте на https://jsfiddle.net/ код, чтобы можно было смотреть и редактировать сообществу

Comment: @mepihindeveloper jsfiddle и прочие codepen запрещены правилами сайта, заливать нужно прямо в текст вопроса

Answer (score 0):

тут проблема не в тэгах, дело в том что img6.jpg (.jpg) хороший формат, но прозрачные пиксели он не поддерживает, саму картинку лучше взять .png, с ним другое дело...
У них эта картинка:
[вот](https://static.tildacdn.com/tild3235-6266-4664-b732-646265303161/WhatsApp_Image_2020-.png)

Comment: Дополните свой ответ – например, рабочим кодом или ссылками на документацию.